# Store scrape results and search in results with Python and Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

as part of my Ph.D. research, I am scraping numerous webpages and search for keywords within the scrape results.

This is how I do it thus far:

```
# load data with as pandas data frame with column df.url
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xls', header=0)

# define keyword search function

def contains_keywords(link, keywords):
    try:
        output = requests.get(link).text
        return int(any(x in output for x in keywords))
    except:
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"

# define the relevant keywords
mykeywords = ('for', 'bar')

# store search results in new column 'results'
df['results'] = df.url.apply(lambda l: contains_keywords(l, mykeywords))
```

This works just fine. I only have one problem: the list of relevant keywords `mykeywords`changes frequently, whilst the webpages stay the same. Running the code takes a long time, since I `request` over and over.

I have two questions:

(1) Is there a way to store the results of `request.get(link).text`?

(2) And if so, how to I search within the saved file(s) producing the same result as with the current script?

As always, thank you for your time and help! /R

Comment: Just save them in files in a `urls` dir and replace this line: `output = requests.get(link).text` with: `output = open('urls/'+link).read()`

Comment: Does this prodcue several files I can later index? Wouldn't I need to specify a file name for each url requested?

Comment: a) Download the content of each link and save it on local disk - use a suitable name, eg: "some.site.com_some_path.html"  b) Pass the name of the file in `contains_keywords` and read the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's my idea. But I have around 1800 URLs in the pandas data frame and I did not manage to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the content of the urls and save them in separate files in a directory (eg: 'links')

```
def get_link(url): 
    file_name = os.path.join('/path/to/links', url.replace('/', '_').replace(':', '_'))
    try: 
        r = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failded to get " + url)
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
            f.write(r.text)
```

Then modify the `contains_keywords` function to read local files, so you won't have to use `requests` every time you run the script.

```
def contains_keywords(link, keywords):
    file_name = os.path.join('/path/to/links', link.replace('/', '_').replace(':', '_'))
    try: 
        with open(file_name) as f: 
            output = f.read()
        return int(any(x in output for x in keywords))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Can't access file: {}\n{}".format(file_name, e))
        return "Wrong/Missing URL"
```

Edit: i just added a try-except block in `get_link` and used absolute path for `file_name`

Comment: Super, nice ! Thank you!